# Problem with Geometry SRID in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, srid

I ceated my table (borne) in PostGIS

```
id_borne serial NOT NULL,
  num_borne character varying,
  shape_borne geometry
```

I successfully changed the SRID of my table using

```
select UpdateGeometrySRID('public', 'borne', 'shape_borne', 26191) ;
```

The old SRID was 0.

The problem is that when I try to add a new element to my table `borne` I have this message error:

```
geometry srid (0) does not match column srid (26191)
```

---

[image]

That is my problem! The SRID is updated but when I try to add a new point, I get this message.

Comment: make sure you give your data a SRID that matches the table before trying to insert it.

Comment: i dont understand , the srid of my data is the srid of my table ! it is the same , no ?

Comment: can you show us one of your insert statements?

Comment: like this :
INSERT INTO borne(num_borne, shape_borne)  VALUES(1, POINT(25800 , 256000));

Comment: The geometry In your insert statement does not have a srid. That is the cause of the error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What's happening is that the data you are trying to insert does not have an SRID assigned.  To assign one, try wrapping the inserted geometry in your insert statement with ST_SetSRID().  E.g.,

```
INSERT INTO public.borne (num_borne, shape_borne) 
    (SELECT num_borne, ST_SetSRID(shape_borne, 26191)
     FROM public.sometable);
```

or

```
INSERT INTO public.borne (num_borne, shape_borne) 
VALUES (1, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(25800 , 256000), 26191));
```

Comment: i dont have some table

Comment: Updated to include your use case.

Comment: it did not work !

Comment: What is the error message?  also, try running: `select find_srid('public', 'borne', 'shape_borne');` to make sure that the srid is actually set on the field.

Comment: it's ok!  it s working with using 

INSERT INTO public.borne (num_borne, shape_borne) 
VALUES (1, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(25800 , 256000), 26191));

it is mandatory to use ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint( ... )
for adding in this table ? 
for my other table (parcelle) it's wortking with a normal request  for exmple : 

INSERT INTO parcelle(num_parcelle, shape) VALUES(1, POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0)));

Answer (score 6):

If you are typing a geometry's WKT into pgAdmin III, you need to specify the SRID using EWKT syntax, otherwise it defaults to 0.

Type this into the geometry field of pgAdmin III:

```
SRID=26191;POINT(25800 256000)
```

Otherwise, @MakinFlippyFloppy has the correct SQL way, using ST_SetSRID.

Answer (score 0):

I thin below link can help you, Check out below page ::

https://postgis.net/docs/UpdateGeometrySRID.html

Comment: I already work with this function !