# UPDATE geometry in table for a specific row

Tags: postgresql

GIVEN: gisTable (Table) has a geom (geometry) column defined as follows:

```
    ALTER table gisTable ADD column geom geometry (Multipolygon, 4326);
```

I am attempting to run the UPDATE command below which is part of a function I am attempting to debug. The UPDATE command is as follows. my function not shown takes 7 arguments from a vb application (the table name, a primary id , an alternate id and two coordinate pairs (lon/lat) which form the GIS polygon to be inserted.

```
    UPDATE thisSchema.gisTable SET geom=st_asbinary(st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((37.98 7.51, 38.51 7.51, 38.51 6.98, 37.98 6.98, 37.98 7.51))', 4326)) WHERE mainid = '023456' AND altId = 'ABC';
```

When I execute the command above the error states that the SRID is not found or is SRID(0); however I am setting it in the st_geomfromtext portion of this clause.

Questions:
Can I use POLYGON even though the geom column was defined as Multipolygon (above)
When I modify POLYGON to MULTIPOLYGON I get a parse error after the first coordinate.

Should the POLYGON clause be wrapped in two (( and )) as shown above.

I have the following function I am using to update each row in gis_table' geom column;

Comment: I saw this comment in this post: [link] https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104607/problem-with-geometry-srid-in-postgis

Comment: I'm also using pgAdmin3 to test the above UPDATE command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not use polygon if the column is defined as multipolygons.
For update you could use this command.

```
  UPDATE gisTable 
  SET geom=
  st_multi((st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((37.98 7.51, 38.51 7.51, 38.51 6.98, 37.98 6.98, 37.98 7.51))', 4326))) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I mad the following modification and successfully UPDATED the geom column

```
    UPDATE thisSchema.gisTable SET geom=st_geomfromtext('MULTIPOLYGON(((37.98 7.51, 38.51 7.51, 38.51 6.98, 37.98 6.98, 37.98 7.51)))', 4326) WHERE mainid = '023456' AND altId  = 'ABC';
```

The MULTIPOLY clause needs ((( and ))) and st_asbinary was not needed.
Any other thoughts???